# For polynomial prove that $r(x)=0$ or $\deg [r_k(x)]<\deg [b(x)]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $a(x),b(x)\in \mathbb R[x]$, $\deg(b(x)) \geq 1$. Show that there exists $m=0,1,\dots$ and $r_0(x),\dots,r_m(x)\in\mathbb R[x]$ such that

$$ a(x)=r_0(x)+r_1(x)b(x) + \cdots + r_m(x)b(x)^m$$

with the property that either $r_k(x)=0$ or $\deg[r_k(x)] < \deg[b(x)]$ for all $k = 0,1,\dots$.

Is it possible to use induction for this question? Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, since $r_i,b$ can be chosen arbitrarily and $a$ defined by $\sum_i r_i b^i$.

Comment: @Martin, thanks,yes you're correct, I've modified it slightly, is it correct now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d$ be the degree of $b(x)$. We show by induction on $n$ that the result is true for all polynomials of degree $\lt nd$.

For the induction step, we need to show that if the result is true for all $a(x)$ of degree $\lt nd$, then it is true for all $a(x)$ of degree $\lt (n+1)d$. So we only need to deal with $a(x)$ of degree $\ge nd$, and $\lt (n+1)d$.

For the proof of the induction step. we can proceed as follows. By the ordinary "Division Algorithm" for polynomials, there is an $r_0(x)$ with the right degree restriction, and a polynomial $q(x)$, such that $a(x)=r_0(x)+q(x)b(x)$.

Show that $q(x)$ has degree $\lt nd$. Then by the induction hypothesis $q(x)$ can be expressed in the right form, and now from $a(x)=r_0(x)+q(x)b(x)$ we get the right form for $a(x)$.

Note that this is an analogue for polynomials of the ordinary base $b$ expansion of positive integers.

Comment: Thanks André for your answer, it is very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. This was the "bottom up" version. For the "top down" version, for $a(x)$ not identically $0$, let $(b(x))^k$ be the highest power of $b(x)$ such that $dk \le n$, where $n$ is the degree of $a_n(x)=a_x$. Let the **quotient** be $r_k(x)$, and the remainder be $a_{n-1}(x)$. By the induction hypothesis on $n$, the result is true for $a_{n-1}(x)$, and we are finished.